# Facing problem with late, undertime and totalHoursWorked in Java

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time with this one.

I made a project for Payroll which calculates the weekly worktime, undertime and late hours; Which meets the following conditions

```
> An employee is considered LATE if he/she logged in beyond 10 minutes from 8AM (ex.8:11 AM and above) 
> An employee is considered LATE if he/she logged in beyond 10 minutes from 1PM (ex.1:11 AM and above)
> An employee is considered UNDERTIME if he/she logged-out 15 minutes prior to 12NN (ex. 11:45 PM and above) 
> An employee is considered UNDERTIME if he/she logged-out 15 minutes prior to 5PM (ex. 4:45 PM and above)
```

What I did is initialize some variables

```
String [] days= {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
String [] tokyotumari={"Morning", "Afternoon"};
int  late=0, loghourIn=0, logminsIn=0,logminsOut=0, loghourOut=0, count=0;
int lateM=0, lateA=0, OrigLate=0, OrigUndertime=0, latehourM, latehourA,totalworkhours=0, LateTime=0, late2=0, under=0, under2=0, Undertime=0;
```

I made 2 loops. The outside is for the days while the inside loop calculates and ask everything.

```
for (int x=0; x < 5; x++){
            count++;
            System.out.println (days[x]);
    for (int y=0; y < 2; y++){
          System.out.println (tokyotumari[y]);
                    System.out.println ("Enter login: ");
                    String login=scan.next();
                    System.out.println ("Enter logout: ");
                    String logout=scan.next();
                        
                    String in[]=login.split(":");
                    String out[]=logout.split(":");
                    loghourIn=Integer.parseInt(in[0]);
                    logminsIn=Integer.parseInt(in[1]);
                    loghourOut=Integer.parseInt(out[0]);
                    logminsOut=Integer.parseInt(out[1]);
                            
                            //total worked time
            lateM=loghourIn%8;
            lateA=loghourOut%1;
            totalworkhours = totalworkhours + (loghourIn - loghourOut);
                             
                             //Determines if late or not in hours.
if ((lateM <= 4) && (lateM > 0)) {
            late= (late + logminsIn) -10;
                     }
if ((lateA <= 4) && (lateA > 0)){
            late2= (late2 + logminsOut)-10;
                    }
if ((lateM == 0) && (logminsIn >= 15)){
             under= (60-logminsIn)-15;
}
if ((lateA == 0) && (logminsOut >= 15)){
              under2=(60-logminsOut)-15;
} 
    
                    LateTime=late+late2;
                    Undertime=under+under2;
                    OrigLate=OrigLate+LateTime;
                    OrigUndertime=OrigUndertime+Undertime;
                    LateTime=0;
                    Undertime=0;
                    late=0;                  
                    late2=0;
                    under=0;
                    under2=0;     
    } // end of inside loop
                    System.out.print (OrigLate+" "+OrigUndertime+" "+totalworkhours);
                
    }// end of inside loop
```

What I got is the result :

```
Monday
Morning
Enter login: 
8:00
Enter logout: 
12:00
Afternoon
Enter login: 
1:30
Enter logout: 
5:00
20 0 -8Tuesday
Morning
Enter login: 
7:50
Enter logout: 
11:30
Afternoon
Enter login: 
1:15
Enter logout: 
5:10
25 15 -16Wednesday
Morning
Enter login: 
8:15
Enter logout: 
11:45
Afternoon
Enter login: 
1:10
Enter logout: 
4:44
25 46 -22Thursday
Morning
Enter login: 
8:20
Enter logout: 
11:40
Afternoon
Enter login: 
1:30
Enter logout: 
4:30
45 91 -28Friday
Morning
Enter login: 
9:00
Enter logout: 
11:00
Afternoon
Enter login: 
12:30
Enter logout: 
5:00
```

Output: Late: 55 Undertime: 91 totalworkhours: 23

Any idea what's going on? The expected output would be:

Late : 1 hour and 50 minutes (which would be 110)
Undertime: 1 hour and 11 minutes (which should be 71)
Working hours: 36 hours and 59 minutes

Any idea how to do this one or where did I go wrong?

Comment: The way you write your `if` clauses is really strange since normally you write a new `if` clause starting on a new line. This of course brings up the question, did you mean to write `else if`?

Comment: I did an if only because if I use the else if, it ignores the other condition. There are other conditions that would meet and I don't want that to be ignored.

Comment: Ok but then start each of them on a new line to increase readability. As for the actual question I think you should use a debugger for this.

Comment: *Edited the code because I didn't post the whole code, my bad*

Comment: I'm using Eclipse for debugging. This is just logical error and I'm not pro-efficient in math (Which makes it something seems wrong with the calculations) .

Comment: Please indent the code properly. It looks like the if block should be inside the for-loop, but it isn't indented that way. This makes it difficult to read. This is also a good case for a [mre].

Comment: Done. I labeled it as clear as possible.

Comment: I understand that a person is supposed to work from 8 am until 12 noon and then from 1 pm until 5 pm. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Supposedly, the program will calculate the total time the employee worked and counts the undertime, late hours of worked and the total hours worked. The example was given above as my input but the expected output is really far from my program's output.

Comment: Can you use the Java time classes, like LocalDateTime?

Comment: Yes but im not familiar with that one. But I prefer using split since I want to explode the ":" Regex and I'm not sure if it can get my result. You can do it if you want to answer my problem and I'll try to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code is not a complete answer. It only calculates the late login minutes. But I think that it is enough to enable you to complete your program since calculating the early logouts and the total hours worked both use the same kind of calculation.

The below code uses the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) that was introduced in Java 8.

```java
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WorkHour {
    private static final LocalTime  LATE_MORNING_LOGIN = LocalTime.parse("08:10");
    private static final LocalTime  LATE_AFTERNOON_LOGIN = LocalTime.parse("13:10");
    private static final LocalTime  EARLY_MORNING_LOGOUT = LocalTime.parse("11:45");
    private static final LocalTime  EARLY_AFTERNOON_LOGOUT = LocalTime.parse("16:45");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Duration lateLogin = Duration.ZERO;
        for (DayOfWeek weekday : DayOfWeek.values()) {
            if (weekday != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY  &&  weekday != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
                System.out.printf("%-9s morning login    [hh:mm]: ", weekday);
                String aTime = scan.nextLine();
                aTime += " AM";
                LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(aTime, timeFormatter);
                if (lt.isAfter(LATE_MORNING_LOGIN)) {
                    lateLogin = lateLogin.plus(Duration.between(lt, LATE_MORNING_LOGIN));
                }
                System.out.printf("%-9s morning logout   [hh:mm]: ", weekday);
                aTime = scan.nextLine();
                if (Integer.parseInt(aTime.substring(0, 2)) == 12) {
                    aTime += " PM";
                }
                else {
                    aTime += " AM";
                }
                lt = LocalTime.parse(aTime, timeFormatter);
                System.out.printf("%-9s afternoon login  [hh:mm]: ", weekday);
                aTime = scan.nextLine();
                aTime += " PM";
                lt = LocalTime.parse(aTime, timeFormatter);
                if (lt.isAfter(LATE_AFTERNOON_LOGIN)) {
                    lateLogin = lateLogin.plus(Duration.between(lt, LATE_AFTERNOON_LOGIN));
                }
                System.out.printf("%-9s afternoon logout [hh:mm]: ", weekday);
                aTime = scan.nextLine();
                aTime += " PM";
                lt = LocalTime.parse(aTime, timeFormatter);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(lateLogin);
    }
}
```

Note that you may not require the `Locale.ENGLISH` argument when creating a `DateTimeFormatter` if your default `Locale` is ENGLISH.

Below is a sample run of the above code – using the sample values in your question.

```
MONDAY    morning login    [hh:mm]: 8:00
MONDAY    morning logout   [hh:mm]: 12:00
MONDAY    afternoon login  [hh:mm]: 1:30
MONDAY    afternoon logout [hh:mm]: 5:00
TUESDAY   morning login    [hh:mm]: 7:50
TUESDAY   morning logout   [hh:mm]: 11:30
TUESDAY   afternoon login  [hh:mm]: 1:15
TUESDAY   afternoon logout [hh:mm]: 5:10
WEDNESDAY morning login    [hh:mm]: 8:15
WEDNESDAY morning logout   [hh:mm]: 11:45
WEDNESDAY afternoon login  [hh:mm]: 1:10
WEDNESDAY afternoon logout [hh:mm]: 4:44
THURSDAY  morning login    [hh:mm]: 8:20
THURSDAY  morning logout   [hh:mm]: 11:40
THURSDAY  afternoon login  [hh:mm]: 1:30
THURSDAY  afternoon logout [hh:mm]: 4:30
FRIDAY    morning login    [hh:mm]: 9:00
FRIDAY    morning logout   [hh:mm]: 11:00
FRIDAY    afternoon login  [hh:mm]: 12:30
FRIDAY    afternoon logout [hh:mm]: 5:00
PT-1H-50M
```

Note that the value of `lateLogin` is one hour and fifty minutes – as you expect it to be.

Comment: I'm really not familiar with the new Java 8 Date-time api but I think it's worth the translate into later version of java 7. I'll mark this as an accepted answer. Thank you !